# MATLAB: Insert leading rows in every slice of 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I need to insert some leading zeros in every slice of a 3D matrix. I am wondering whether there is a more elegant way rather than using a for-loop, such as this one:

```
orig3D = rand(5,1,2);

for n = 1 : 2
    new3D(:,:,n) = [zeros(3,1); orig3D(:,:,n)];
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code can be vectorised, avoiding the loop:

`new3D = [zeros(3,1,2); orig3D];`